# Exclude folder from .war file

Tags: maven, tomcat, spark-java

I am new in maven. My maven for war building is as follows

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <configuration>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        <webXml>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
        <packagingIncludes>resources/src/**</packagingIncludes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

My application is a spark-java web application. I am also using angular2. Typescript and related library files are in ***src/main/resources/src/*** folder. I am using gulp to compile the typescrpt files and the generated files go to ***src/main/resources/public/*** folder. I want to exclude all the files and sub folders from ***src/main/resources/src/***.

I have tried both packagingIncludes and warSourceExcludes but not working for me. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: *and the generated files go to src/main/resources/public/ folder*: please, don't do that. Never. Generate files under `target`. A different location means pain and suffering for you, nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude the whole directory like this:

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources/src/</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>*</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

Or change the folder to: "src/main/typescript".